# Bounded orbit is compact?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Maybe this is a foolish question but if we have a dynamical system, for example an ODE, and are talking about orbits (or trajectories), aren't bounded orbits $x_t$ automatically compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

In other words: Are (bounded) orbits closed sets?

Comment: No, orbits are "usually" not closed. Think of [irrational rotation on a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation), the [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system), etc. If instead you're talking about discrete dynamics, an infinite bounded orbit is _never_ closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And if we add the property that the $\omega$-limit set contains exactly one element? Does this make the orbit closed?

Comment: The limit set is not part of a non-recurrent orbit, but is in the closure.

Comment: I am just wondering since I was told to use compactness of the bounded orbit $x_t$ to show that $x_t\to\omega^*$ in case the $\omega$-limit set contains one element, i.e. $\Omega(x_t)=\left\{\omega^*\right\}$. Now I do not know how to show that the bounded orbit is closed (in order to have compactness = bounded + closed).

Comment: Use the compactness of the _closure_ of the orbit.

Comment: I try: By $\bar{x_t}$ denote the closure of the orbit $(x_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$. $\bar{x_t}$ is bounded (since $x_t$ is bounded) and closed (by definition). Hence it is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, in particular, sequentially compact. That is, each sequence in $\bar{x_t}$ has a convergent subsequence; in particular, each subsequence of $(x_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ has a convergent subsequence which has to converge to $\omega^*$ since otherwise there would be another element in $\Omega(x_t)$. From this it follows that $(x_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ converges to $\omega^*$ (by analysis 1). Ok?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I always thought of orbits as closed sets: If I consider an open ball around a point on an orbit, the full open ball does not belong to the orbits... where is my mistake?

Comment: @Rhjg: For your first question, you need to consider sequences for which $t \to \infty$. Otherwise your argument looks good. To address your second question, think of an interval, say $(0, 1)$, embedded in the _plane_. The interval is, in a sense, "locally closed". The problem is the missing endpoints.

Comment: But if I think f.e. of the orbits of harmonic oscillator they are closed sets?